# In PHP when using ternary operator (?:) what are benefits/damage of evaluating multiple conditions at a time?

Tags: php

Having a hard time finding the words to phrase this but every example using ternary always uses a single condition

```
$x = ($x > 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

```
$x = (any single evaluation) ? if true : if false;
```

Above, is how all example that I found are structured.

My question though is about the structure below, specifically using here the &&

```
$x = (($x > 1) && ($z === 0)) ? 1 : 0;
```

So my question is whether using the format of my last example above is frowned upon or causes issues since I have never seen it used or its benefits/damage explained.

Comment: its fine its no different than doing `if (blah && blah) {`

Comment: Last statement can be rewritten into more concise form using explicit type juggling: `$x = (int)($x > 1 && $z === 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible issue is that the more complex your condition, the harder it is to read. There comes a point where it's just easier to read `if( ... ) {$x = 1;} else {$x = 0;}` than the ternary operator alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's about readability and style.

I usually use the ternary operator for **very simple settings** only.

That is:

```
$x = isset($y) ? $y : "default";
```

Anything more complex than that, should go to an if statement.

---

However, that is my personal writing style. Adopt one of your own and stick to it.